# How to get Boolean answer if each name in an excel column has a matching date to it or not

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get a Boolean answer if all orders made by "name" were made on the same date.
I have a column of orders (marked by names) in column L and each order is made on a set date in column G and i have an index of all unique customer names in column Z.

so i basically want a formula that for each name in column Z it goes through column L and checks if the name matches, it extracts the date from column G. then it checks if all the extracted dates match or not

Comment: Use Match()` function. Post some of your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(L:L,Z1)=COUNTIFS(L:L,Z1,G:G,INDEX(G:G,MATCH(Z1,L:L,0)))
```

Place it anywhere (presumably in cell AA1) and drag it down as needed. If you list of names starts in cell Z2, just use the same formula but substitute Z1 with Z2.

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).